# Wrong value in memory because of a branch misprediction

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture

Lets say we have instructions like:

```asm
bne r1 $0 loop
sw r2 0(r1)
```

Let's say we go ahead with the taken path, i.e., execute the sw instruction after bne assuming the branch is Not Taken. On a branch misprediction (bne turns out to be Not Taken), how do we update the data memory/ cache with the correct value because sw was not supposed to be executed and change the values in memory and corrupt it? I am asking this question concerning both an R10K/P6 OOO core and a simple 5-stage pipeline core.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_stall  For most software, reads are more common than writes.

Comment: A key feature of branch prediction is that you need to have a mechanism that allows you to defer committing (to registers or memory) the results of any speculative operations until you actually know the result of the branch.